# Signal bandwidth by constraints, for a real signal?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Given a real signal $s$ such that $$|s(t)|< a,$$ $s'(t)$ is continuous, and $$|s'(t)| <b,$$

what, if anything, can be said of the bandwidth of $s(t)$?

Comment: What sort of things are you wishing you could say?

Comment: Well I would like to say that the maximum frequency would be below something.